# dvips / mktexpk can't find font

Tags: texlive, dvips

I have an application that builds input for LaTeX, runs latex on that input, runs `dvips` on the output, and converts that file to an image.  I just deployed the application to a new server with the 2012 version of TeXLive (instead of the 2011 version that I have successfully used in other deployments).  I have run `texhash` and `updmap-sys`.  TexLive was installed under root user on Ubuntu Server 10.4.  I would like to get the app working on this server with TeXLive-2012 if I can.  The problem is that my images look very wrong.  Fonts are wayyy too small, spacing is off, etc., etc..  I am assuming that pdftex is fine with the fonts because PDFs produced from the same `.tex` files look fine.

I am getting the following output in the terminal:

```
Executing thread: dvips -D 1200 my_file.dvi
This is dvips(k) 5.98 Copyright 2009 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2013.01.28:1129' -> my_file.ps

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 1200 --mag 1+0/1200 --dpi 1200 ecbx1000
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ecbx1000.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
dvips: Font ecbx1000 not found,  using cmr10 instead.
</usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font ecbx1000

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 1200 --mag 1+0/1200 --dpi 1200 ecrm1000
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ecrm1000.
dvips: Font ecrm1000 not found,  using cmr10 instead.
</usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font ecrm1000
```

I don't get error output like this on my dev machine (OSX, TeXLive-2011) and my images look fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose its possible that my problem and the observed console output are unrelated...gotta start somewhere though.

Comment: You seem to be missing the EC fonts; and the CM-Super bundle for having them also in Type1 format.

Comment: As egreg wrote, install these two fonts. If you are running upstream TeX Live 2012, install them with `tlmgr install cm-super ec`, and if you are using the Debian/Ubuntu version of TL2012, then install them with `apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended cm-super`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks good people.  One clarification please -- I installed TL2012 on Ubuntu 10.04 using the tl_install script rather than with apt-get.  Should I run both of the aforementioned commands? or just one or the other (which)?

Answer (score 1):

The fonts you are asking for are not installed in a minimal system, so please proceed as follows: As egreg wrote, install these two fonts. If you are running upstream TeX Live 2012, install them with `tlmgr install cm-super ec`, and if you are using the Debian/Ubuntu version of TL2012, then install them with `apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended cm-super`, that should do the trick.